# How to view the bigquery jobs metadata correctly? INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, metadata

i'd like to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION` in bigquery to search and find the jobs between projects which are pointing to specific tables.

I did it with my own project using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` but i can't see the ORGANIZATION'S one to ask between projects.

"Access Denied: Table bc-te-dlake-dev-s7b3:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION: User does not have permission to query table bc-te-dlake-dev-s7b3:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION."

I have the "organization administrator" rol in my project.

Answer (score 9):

Along with the correct permissions, make sure you have the project and region in your query e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `myproject`.`region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER;
```

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#required_permissions

`JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION requires bigquery.jobs.listAll for the organization and is available to the Organization bigquery.resourceAdmin, Organization Owner and Organization Admin roles. Note that JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION is only available to users with defined Google Cloud organizations.`

Verify you have all the required roles at the org as defined in the above docs

Comment: the problem is that i have "Organization Admin" but i'm still not able to see the metadata

Comment: @CRISTIANERNESTOTOROLOPEZ - Do not assume Organization Admin has all permissions. Hint: It does not.